# Convert JSON Epoch to DateTime in Ruby for Conversion to CSV File

Tags: json, ruby, csv, datetime, epoch

Hello Stack Overflow Friends,

We use an email metric API that returns data requested in JSON. What I am attempting to do is convert the JSON to a CSV file in Ruby (which I have been able to successfully do using the [json-converter gem](https://github.com/cescue/json-to-csv)). But, obviously JSON returns date/time fields in Epoch which is useless to most people. Therefore, I'm trying to figure out 2 things:

1) How to appropriately convert Epoch into a more human-readable date/time for the CSV file, and

2) Where along the way in my Ruby code do I need to attempt to do this - before the JSON to CSV conversion or after?

Here's the sample code so far:

**JSON Response**

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 571823,
      "subCommunityId": 2,
      "emailName": "Email Name",
      "fromName": "John Doe",
      "fromAddress": "john@doe.com",
      "subjectLine": "This is my subject",
      "preHeader": "",
      "categoryName": "General Communication",
      "sentCount": 15678,
      "scheduledDateTimestamp": 1504889858000,
      "actualSendTimestamp": 1504889858000,
      "dateAdded": 1504889859576
    }
  ],
  "startAt": 0,
  "maxResults": 1000,
  "total": 1
}
```

**Ruby Script - JSON to CSV**

```
require 'json_converter'
converter = JsonConverter.new
json = File.read("emailresponse.json")
converter.write_to_csv(json, "emailreporting.csv")
```

Any thoughts on how best to do this are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, Ruby already can build CSV.

```
require 'json'
require 'csv'

json = '{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 571823,
      "subCommunityId": 2,
      "emailName": "Email Name",
      "fromName": "John Doe",
      "fromAddress": "john@doe.com",
      "subjectLine": "This is my subject",
      "preHeader": "",
      "categoryName": "General Communication",
      "sentCount": 15678,
      "scheduledDateTimestamp": 1504889858000,
      "actualSendTimestamp": 1504889858000,
      "dateAdded": 1504889859576
    }
  ],
  "startAt": 0,
  "maxResults": 1000,
  "total": 1
}'
hash = JSON.parse(json)

CSV.open('emailreporting.csv', 'w') do |csv| 
  # write headers row
  csv << hash['data'].first.keys 

  # write data rows
  hash['data'].each do |data| 
    data['scheduledDateTimestamp'] = Time.at(data['scheduledDateTimestamp'] / 1000)
    data['actualSendTimestamp'] = Time.at(data['actualSendTimestamp'] / 1000) 
    data['dateAdded'] = Time.at(data['dateAdded'] / 1000) 
    csv << data.values  
  end
end
```

Building CSV manually gives some advantages:

1. using Ruby's standard library rather than some little-known gem
2. more control during building csv

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Ruby's built-in `Date`, `DateTime`, and `Time` classes can handle these types of conversions rather easily. Here are a couple options:

```
Time.at(1504889858000/1000).to_datetime.to_s
=> "2017-09-08 12:57:38 -0400"
```

...

```
require 'date'
DateTime.strptime((1504889858000/1000).to_s, '%s').to_s
=> "2017-09-08T16:57:38+00:00"
```

As for how to handle the logic in your program. One way would be to pull the JSON from your file into a ruby Hash. Then change the values associated with any keys where the values are timestamps. Then pass the hash to your converter library for writing. Something like this might do it:

```
require 'json'

f = File.read('emailresponse.json')
hash_of_stuff = JSON.parse(f)
hash_of_stuff['scheduledDateTimestamp'] = Time.at(hash_of_stuff['scheduledDateTimestamp']/1000).to_datetime.to_s
...
converter.write_to_csv(hash_of_stuff, 'endresult.csv')
```